# Related to tabbar control in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Thanks in advance.
  I want to add two tabbar controllers one at top and another at bottom like [image]
this. Is it possible in iphone. IF possible and any one know please help me to do this.

Comment: I guess it is not possible you need to have customize tab Bar.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it should be possible to do that. Just add one to your view and the other one to your rootviewcontroller, in different positions, and you should be able to link to different places. If not, just pull up photoshop, "make" the tab bar and put buttons underneath it to simulate the effect.

PS, samantha is gorgeous! haha

Answer (score 0):

UITabBar is dificult to modify in ANY direction.

Much easyer will be replace it with your own, custom one. Offcorse, it can be anything you like. Look at this:

```
//CustomTabBar.h:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomTabBar : UITabBarController {
    UIButton *SHOPPING;
    UIButton *DINING;
    UIButton *MAPS;
    UIButton *PARKING;
    UIButton *PROMOTION;
    UIImageView *BarBackground;
}
-(void) addCustomElements;
-(void) hideExistingTabBar;
-(void) selectTab:(int)tabID;
@end

//CustomTabBar.m:
#import "CustomTabBar.h"

@implementation CustomTabBar

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self hideExistingTabBar];
    [self addCustomElements];
}

- (void)hideExistingTabBar
{
    for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            view.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)addCustomElements
{
    //in your case you will need 2 bars, but I needed only one. Just add another one.
    BarBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarBackground.jpg"]];
    BarBackground.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 320, 50);

    // Initialise our two images
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarShipping.png"];
    UIImage *btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarShipping.png"];

    SHOPPING = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; //Setup the button
    SHOPPING.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 64, 50); // Set the frame (size and position) of the button)
    [SHOPPING setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal]; // Set the image for the normal state of the button
    [SHOPPING setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected]; // Set the image for the selected state of the button
    [SHOPPING setTag:0]; // Assign the button a "tag" so when our "click" event is called we know which button was pressed.
    [SHOPPING setSelected:true]; // Set this button as selected (we will select the others to false as we only want Tab 1 to be selected initially

    // Now we repeat the process for the other buttons
    btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarDinning.png"];
    btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarDinning.png"];
    DINING = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    DINING.frame = CGRectMake(64, 430, 64, 50);
    [DINING setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [DINING setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [DINING setTag:1];
    <...>


    // Add my new buttons to the view
    [self.view addSubview:BarBackground];
    [self.view addSubview:SHOPPING];
    [self.view addSubview:DINING];
    <...>


    // Setup event handlers so that the buttonClicked method will respond to the touch up inside event.
    [SHOPPING addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [DINING addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    <...>
}

- (void)selectTab:(int)tabID
{
    //if you will need navigation controller, or something, you will need to work on this part, or it will just crash.
    switch(tabID)
    {
        case 0:
            [SHOPPING setSelected:true];
            [DINING setSelected:false];
            <...>
            break;
        case 1:
            [SHOPPING setSelected:false];
            [DINING setSelected:true];
            <...>
            break;
        <...>
    }   

    if (self.selectedIndex == tabID) {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[self selectedViewController];
        [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        self.selectedIndex = tabID;
    }

}

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    int tagNum = [sender tag];
    [self selectTab:tagNum];
}

@end
```

Then, just add and use TabBarController as usual. The only thing you must do - is change class of TabBarController to this, CastomTabBar in your xib file. (or alloc it with this class, if you adding it programmaticaly: UITabBarController *tb = [[CustomTabBar alloc] init];)
And one more thing: there is a place, that presentet for tabBar, so your view resized usual. If you use this code, it will be too, but at usual tabBar place - at the bottom. For second tabBar you will need to prepare place yourself. Hope, this will help.